# How can I get systemd to grab service logs from a docker image?

Tags: docker, logging, systemd

So, as the title suggests, I have a containerized service running in docker, and I have a systemd service unit to manage said service automatically. Alongside that, I would like to have the logs for the docker container sent to the service logs. Is there any way I could have the logs provided in the `docker logs SERVICE` command piped to the output of the systemd service logs?

My first attempt at this was to set an `ExecStartPost` call to `docker logs -f SERVICE`, however that did not seem to work as restarting the service provided an error. I did also find [this link](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/) about logging to journald, and I get the feeling this may be on the right track, but I see no explicit way provided to pipe that *specifically* to the systemd service in question.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Docker uses the [json-file](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/) logging driver. This writes to a flat json file on disk. You would need some external tool to parse those logs if you continued to use it which would be a complete complex mess, so you should definitely change it.

You are correct in your original assessment: Use the [journald logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/) in your scenario. You would need to use the [tag](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/#options) system to set the appropriate `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER` value.

```
tag optional    Specify template to set CONTAINER_TAG and SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER value in journald logs. Refer to log tag option documentation to customize the log tag format.
```

---

Docker logging drivers are listed here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers